# getting full pending transactions from Infura

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, infura

I use Infura to get all pending transactions from Ropsten:

```
web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', async (error, txHash) => {
    let tx = getTransaction(txHash)
    ...
}
```

With this subscription, I receive only the transaction hashes, so I must make a request to get each transaction.

My question: is there a way to receive the full pending transactions with a simple subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter) function in web3 javascript API and you can get pending txs by it. A simple print script as follows:

```
web3.eth.filter("pending").watch(
    function(error,result){
        if (!error) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    } )
```

Hope It will Help You...

Comment: with Infura, I got this error: web3.eth.filter is not a function

Comment: and with web3.eth.subscribe('pending', ...) I got: Unknown subscription: pending

Comment: It appears you are using web3.js v1.0 and make sure you are using callback with the subscribe method. For more see https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-pendingtransactions

Answer (score 0):

Right, the `pendingTransactions` event returns only hashes, but you can optimize the further tx retrieval by creating the batched request with [web3js#batchrequest](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth.html#batchrequest). Wait for `N` new pending transactions (aka tx pool), and request the transactions data at once.